# Is it possible to run selenium RC tests with selenoid?

Tags: selenium-rc, selenoid

Trying to fully move to selenoid, but we still have some legacy RC tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think so. Selenoid only implements Selenium JSONWire and W3C Webdriver protocols. Selenium RC worked by injecting a browser extension and Selenoid has no such feature.